# Node/Socket.io TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:499:33)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, zlib

I'm getting this crash on node when a reload the web page. It doesn't happen everytime. I'd estimate about 10%.

I read another post on this that recommended adding:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    console.log("user disconnected", data);
    return;
  });
```

I have added this but the issue remains.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null
    at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:499:33)
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::Chdir(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x2994b85842fd
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: We are seeing this in our logs as well. Have you arrived at a solution or gathered any addition evidence?

Comment: @BillButler Did you arrived a solution

Comment: @josh did you find out any solution